# web-bluetooth NotSupportedError: GATT operation not permitted

Tags: javascript, web-bluetooth

I am getting error code "NotSupportedError: GATT operation not permitted."
I am trying to connect to ESP32 bluetooth. I tested using nRF Connect and messages are getting to the hardware. Next I tried to use javascript and web-bluetooth. Unfortunately I am getting error on console.error('Argh! ' + error) line of code. The error is happening on characteristic.writeValue()

The code was run on https.

The code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
let bluetoothDevice = null;
let requestDeviceParams = {
    filters: [
        {name: ["konko"]}
    ],
    optionalServices: ['10001001-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb']
}

let name = document.querySelector('#date-input')
$("#synch-date-time").click(() => {
    if (document.querySelector('#date-input').value === '') {
        console.error('empty date field, please fill the fields')
        return
    }
    asyncResultNotif();
})



async function asyncResultNotif(){
    return await navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice(requestDeviceParams)
    .then(device => {
        bluetoothDevice = device.gatt;
       
        return device.gatt.connect();
    })
    .then(server => {
        if (bluetoothDevice.connected) {
            return server.getPrimaryService('10001001-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb');
        } else {
            console.log('cant connect to prime server')
        }
    })
    .then(service => {
        if (bluetoothDevice.connected) {
            return service.getCharacteristic('10001111-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb'); // write one value
        } else {
            console.log('cant connect to characteristic')
        }
    })
    .then(characteristic => {
        if (bluetoothDevice.connected) {
            // const resetEnergyExpended = Uint8Array.of(1);
            // return characteristic.writeValue(resetEnergyExpended);
            let data = '{"ssid": "' +name.value
                data +='"}'
                console.log(data)
            let encoder = new TextEncoder('utf-8');
            let val = encoder.encode(data);
            // return characteristic.writeValue(val.buffer)
            
            return characteristic.writeValue(new Uint8Array([1]))
        } else {
            console.log('cant send message over BLE')
        }
    }). then(() => {
            if (bluetoothDevice.connected) {
                bluetoothDevice.disconnect();
            } else {
                console.log('> Bluetooth Device is already disconnected');
            }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error('Argh! ' + error)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the Bluetooth GATT characteristic you're writing to is not writable. Can you share your ESP32 server code as well?

It should look something like below. Note that I use `BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE`.

```cpp
  class MyCallbacks: public BLECharacteristicCallbacks {
    void onWrite(BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic) {
      std::string value = pCharacteristic->getValue();

  BLECharacteristic *pCharacteristic = pService->createCharacteristic(
                                         CHARACTERISTIC_UUID,
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_READ |
                                         BLECharacteristic::PROPERTY_WRITE
                                       );

  pCharacteristic->setCallbacks(new MyCallbacks());
  pCharacteristic->setValue("Hello World");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The problem was with UUID of characteristic. On ESP32 it was "10001111-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" and when I changed that to "10000000-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb" it starts working. I somewhere read that it may be something with 128bits in UUID. We can mark with as answered.